# GeoJSON or TopoJSON outline of Milky Way

Tags: geojson, d3, topojson

I'm looking for a GeoJSON or TopoJSON file with the Milky Way outline on the Sky sphere, for an astronomical almanac web application I'm building with the D3js JavaScript library.

I have searched in vain with google...

The best would be if it has a few layers roughly indicating the brightness levels (brighter in the middle of the disk, and towards the MW centre).

Alternatively, does anybody have an idea how I could create such a file?